# how to Move an item from one div to another selected check box on submit using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi all i am working on jquery here i have a html code like this

```
<div>
    <span class="span1">
      <label class="checkbox" />
          <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" id="Header" />
          <label for="Header"></label>
      </label>
    </span> 
    <span class="span1">Images</span> 
    <span class="span1">SKU</span>
    <span class="span2">Name</span> 
    <span class="span1">Price</span>                             
</div>

<div id="separate"></div>
      <input type="button" id="button" />
```

i had tried like this it dosen't works

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(#button).click(function(){
   $(function () {

      $("input:checkbox").toggle(function () {
         $("#Header").appendTo("#separate");
      },function () {
         $("#separate").appendTo($(this));
      });
      });

   });
</script>
```

i have this `DIV` in which i have a `checkbox` from here i have an image, price and name (cell phone). This is my code and i have a 'href' icon
 when i select the `checkbox`, and i submited the image and price and name should move to another `DIV` how can I do this and when i deselect the `checkbox`?
It should toggle. Could u please help me on how to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Shakil, even after my edit I can hardly understand what are you trying exactly to accomplish here. E.g: you're mentioning some elements like `$("#separate")` that are not present in your HTML markup. Please read again your question and make it understandable. Help us to help you :)

Comment: k thanks for editing i wil now

Comment: sory i wil update now yes i had tried it is #separate is id of another div to append data to that div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it. http://jsbin.com/umivoc/1/

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
  // Check if user clicks on the checkbox
  $("#Header").click(function() {

    if($('#Header').is(':checked')){

      // If the checkbox becomes checked, 
      // move the contents to our new div (div2)
      $("#div1").contents().appendTo("#div2");
    } else {

      // Otherwise we can assume it is being unchecked, 
      // so move everything back to it's original div (div1)
      $("#div2").contents().appendTo("#div1");
    }
  });
});
```

HTML Markup:
I cleaned up your markup quite a bit, you had open label tags, and you should probably put the elements you want to move inside their own wrapper div, to make things easy.

```
<span class="span1">
   <label for="Header"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" id="Header" />
</span> 
<div id="div1">
   <span class="span1">Images</span> 
   <span class="span1">SKU</span>
   <span class="span2">Name</span> 
   <span class="span1">Price</span>                             
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for my reply jeemusu but my task is updated it should work on submit function k and i wil have a no of check boxex and it shold add only selected could u help me plz

Comment: jeemu thanks for my reply look i wil explain u i have  div in this i have some content like image and name and price now i need those image to anothe div onle checked one i wil have multi check boxes

Comment: when i selected the check box and and when i click the button the image should move to anothe div

Comment: it is possible if it's plz help me to do that

Comment: thankyou very much seemu it's working i got it thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you need, but may be to will lead to the solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" id="Header" />
<br/>
Pos:1
<div id="oryginal">
    <span class="span1">Images</span> 
    <span class="span1">SKU</span>
    <span class="span2">Name</span> 
    <span class="span1">Price</span>
</div>                           
<br/>
Pos:2
<div id="separate"></div>​

$("input:checkbox").toggle(
   function () {
         $("#oryginal span").appendTo("#separate");
      },function () {
         $("#separate span").appendTo("#oryginal");
      });
```